# How to show dynamic logo and slogan of website from database using partial files

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I need to show dynamic logo and site slogan from database. Both data are static define in views/includes/topbar.blade.php

view/includes/topbar.blade.php

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <!--top-->
        <div id="top">
            <div class="col-left">
                <div class="africe"> Website Slogan </div>
                <div class="call_us"> call us: <span>+xx-xxxxx</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right">
                <div class="top-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Follow Us:</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
                        <li>
                            <button class="Enquire_now">ENQUIRE NOW</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Just create a blade extension that fetches the correct data from the database. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am already used blade extension but I need to pass data in includes/partial file so how to execute query ?

Comment: I'm talking about _extending_ blade (adding functions to it, like `getSlogan` and `getLogo`). Then you can create functions for getting the data you need from the db, when you need it, in what ever template/partial/component you're in. Here's a direct link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade

Answer (score 0):

You can try [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composershttps://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) for sharing data to all views.

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    //get options model from database
    $options = Model::where('foo', 'bar')->first();

    //passing options to view
    $view->with('options', $options);
}
```

in your view call them like,

```
<div class="col-left">
    <div class="africe"> {{ $options->slogan }} </div>
</div>
```